# Cut ot vs Stop with

Tags: word-usage, usage

> Will you please cut out all your formality?
>
> Will you please stop with all your formality?

Do these sentences sound fine?

Comment: The second is better, but neither is commonly said. What are you trying to convey? As usual, context is extremely helpful.

Comment: Yes, we need context. Neither of the alternatives sounds particularly natural and (ironically) they both sound a bit formal, since formal requests often begin with “Will you please...”. I’d expect to hear something like, “Please stop being so formal.” or perhaps, “Quit the formality please.”